# Decrypt and Encrypted Data on Database

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

How could I possible `decrypt` the `encrypted` data on my database . I am encrypting my data like this

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Best practice in c# to interact with database (using statement)
            using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connection.connectionString))
            {
                mysqlCon.Open();
                //Add the stored procedure that we uses in the mysqlworkbench
                MySqlCommand mysqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("LoginAdd", mysqlCon);
                mysqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //lets encrypt the data
                method.Encrypt(textBox2,hash,results);

                //Use trim to avoid spaces
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_LoginID", LoginID);
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_LoginUser", textBox1.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_LoginPass", textBox2.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Registered Succesfully");
                //proceed to login page
                this.Hide();
                method.ConstantLoginForm();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(""+ ex);
        }
    }
```

Now here's my method for encrypting the data

```
public void Encrypt(TextBox txtEncrypt, string hash, byte[] results)
    {
        hash = "placeholder";
        byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtEncrypt.Text);
        using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
            {
                ICryptoTransform transform = tripDes.CreateEncryptor();
                results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                txtEncrypt.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(results, 0, results.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now my problem is how can I `decrypt` it. What I'm doing is a login system.

Here's my decrypt method

```
public void Decrypt(TextBox txtDecrypt, string hash, byte[] results)
    {
        hash = "placeholder";
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(txtDecrypt.Text); // decrypt the incrypted text
        using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
            {
                ICryptoTransform transform = tripDes.CreateDecryptor();
                results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                //textBox4.Text = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(results);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's what I have done so far

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = textBox1.Text;
        string pass = textBox2.Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(pass))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty Fields Detected!");
            return;
        }
        bool r = validate_login(user, pass);

        if (r)
        {
            this.Hide();
            method.ConstantViewUserForm();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Credentials");
        }
    }

    private bool validate_login(string user, string pass)
    {

        using (MySqlConnection mySqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connection.connectionString))
        {
            mySqlCon.Open();
            MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT *FROM login WHERE loginuser=@username AND loginpass=@password", mySqlCon);

            method.Decrypt(textBox2, hash, results);

            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);

            MySqlDataReader login = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (login.Read())
            {
                mySqlCon.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                mySqlCon.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I just can get the right logic for this .

Comment: The encryption code you have is insecure. It uses 3DES, MD5 and ECB mode...  Literally couldn't be any worse.  Research how to implement *secure* encryption first and come back with any issues.

Comment: You are using a MD5 hash to validate passwords. A hash is an one way encryption, which is used to validate the integrity of a file or string. There is way to decrypt a hash. If you want to validate the user based on username an password, make a hash from the password input from the user and check it against the database.

Comment: If you really want (need) your data encrypted-at-rest, use a professionally written tool. Don't DIY.

Comment: Do not use a reversible encrypting of any form for storing passwords. Bad bad idea which can literally compromise your users' security. Lookup bcrypt, scrypt or argon2 for some good options around password validation.